# What is the meaning of "?" in git repository?

Tags: github, repository, atlassian-sourcetree

I have added some images and class in my project. generally when I add new images it shows "A". But now some of the images show "?". due to that I am not able to add that images in repository. Can anyone tell me what this "?" means and how to resolve it. For reference I have attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The usually means untracked file, so a file that isn't tracked by git yet.

You should be able to stage and commit these files.

Answer (score 0):

This sign(?) simple means that, particular file with `?` symbol is not added to version control(Git or SVN) yet.

Follow this link for [File Status](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) under version control system.

Follow below steps to add untracked files:

1. Select files with `?`
2. Right click and it will open popup menu.
3. Click on `Add To Index`.

[image]

Now, you can able to commit files to git server.